# Как сделать в календаре только определенные даты активными

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Использую, DatePicker в своем проекте, но не работает функция `beforeShowDay`. Вот такой код.

```
var enabledDays = ['11-30-2013', '12-14-2013', '12-21-2013', '3-10-2014', '11-30-2014']

function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
  var m = date.getMonth(),
      d = date.getDate(),
      y = date.getFullYear();
  for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, enabledDays) != -1) {
      return [true];
    }
  }
  return [false];
}

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy', //choose the date format you prefer
  beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но ничего не работает. Все даты по-прежнему остаются активными. 
Использую `bootstrap-datepicker.js`
Как мне сделать активным, только заданный массив дат?

Comment: проблема не воспроизводится. вы datepicker то из jquery UI используете?

Comment: зы: зачем вам там цикл, а внутри `inArray` ? либо одно либо другое выберите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж проверил код, то оставлю ответом. 
Проблема не воспроизводится. Код ваш немного упростил, но работает исправно. Есть сомнения, что вы используйте datepicker из jquery UI. В любом случае, проверьте, вызывается ли ваш коллбэк метод вообще.добавьте внутрь `console.log(date)`.

зы: даты поменял на текущий год-месяц.

```js
$("input").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
  });
  
  
var enabledDays = ['2-1-2018', '2-14-2018', '2-21-2018', '3-10-2018']

function enableAllTheseDays(date) {        
     var cd = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
     return [ $.inArray(cd, enabledDays) != -1 ]     
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<input>
```

---

**апдейт**
судя по стилям у вам бутстраповский datepicker.

заметьте разницу, если в jquery UI документация говорит вернуть массив

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must **return an array** with:
>      [0]: `true/false` indicating whether or not this date is selectable

то в бутспрапе возвращать надо просто булевое значение

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and returns one of the following values:
>          A `Boolean`, indicating whether or not this month is selectabl

```js
var enabledDays = ['2-1-2018', '2-14-2018', '2-21-2018', '2-10-2018'];


$("input").datepicker( { 
    dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy' ,
    
    beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
});



function enableAllTheseDays(date) {        
     var cd = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + date.getFullYear();     
     return $.inArray(cd, enabledDays) != -1 ;          
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link id="bs-css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link id="bsdp-css" href="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
        
<div class="container">
<div class="row" >
 <div class="col-xs-4">
   <input class="form-control input-sm">
 </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я использую bootstrap-datepicker под него этот код не сработает?

Comment: @shatoidil да понял уже что бутстрап, счас допишу ответ

Comment: @shatoidil обновил ответ